# Wordpress: Excluding specific categories from having pagination

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, pagination, posts

Im building a wordpress site that has multiple cateogory pages displayed different places on the site.

Now the theme is developed from the twentyfourteen theme, that comes with pagination on category posts pages. I want to turn the pagination off for only some of the category pages. I hope you can help me.

example on page that needs the pagination turned off:
http://hubnorth.webcamp01.com/category/medlemmer/vinger-nacelle-hub/

Answer (score 0):

You can check the specific categories by using this wordpress function

`<?php is_category( $category ); ?>`

And turn off the pagination for these specific categories.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a conditional statement:

```
if (!is_category(array(1,2,3)): // IDs of categories you dont want pagination.
    // Show Pagination
endif;
```